# how should i exclude certain .php URLs from being loaded through SSL?

Tags: ssl, .htaccess, wordpress

recently i activated flexible SSL on my wordpress website,but i wish to load certain .php URLs through simple http, ones like: thankyou.php and contact.php ,and a few others, what code should i add to my .htaccess file to fix this issue?

Comment: it depend on how is set your https configuration, is it a redirect ?

Comment: yes! it's a redirect that uses cloudflare page rule to redirect all Http URLs to the equivalent HTTPs ones, i need to exclude a couple of .php URLs from this, But don't know how,

Comment: Why would you bother trying to serve certain pages over HTTP, but not others. Either do everything over HTTPS or don't do it at all.

Comment: because those pages contain resources that do not serve well through HTTPS

Answer (score 0):

You redirect to HTTP if a page match a pattern for example :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (thankyou\.php|contact\.php)$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, i added this to my .htaccess file, But still it loads through SSL, i'm using cloudflare redirect that redirects http URLs to HTTPS, could this be the reason?